# iOS background location updates ceasing after a while

Tags: ios, background, cllocation

I am experimenting a funny issues on my app regarding the background updates I use to update the badge number on the basis of some objects thereby. In order to test it I invoked an url and saved the timestamp for the last access on a DB.
Basically the number keeps increasing for a while after I put the app in background to a certain point after some minutes cease updating altogether. I do not think the issue depends on the backgound enabling code, othewise the update would never occur in background.

So what might be the issue? Has anyone experienced the same behaviour and discovered something interesting?

Thanks, Fabrizio

Answer (score 0):

It probably is the background enabling code. By default, iOS lets your app run in the background for a little while before it is killed to free up RAM. In order to actually work in the background (Target iOS8 upward), go to Settings < Capabilities < Background Modes < Location updates like so:

[image: iOS background modes]

Comment: Of course my settings is done in the way. That is the quite trivial stuff. I was just wondering if some completion handler should be called to free memory or some other action performed.

Comment: I have also devised a test project I may sent to you for a local test.